# pandas count rows until cell value changes and plot it

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a data frame which i populate via FFPROBE json output:

`args = [ffprobe, '-hide_banner', '-loglevel', 'quiet', '-show_frames', '-count_frames', '-of', 'json', '-i', fp]`

I'm only interested in the video frames so before populating the data frame i create a new dict from the ffprobe output:

```
video_frames = [i for i in input_frames_info["frames"] if i["media_type"].lower() == "video"]
filtered_frames_video = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(video_frames)
```

at this point, the data frame looks like this:
[image]

My question is how can I create a new dataframe where each row is the sum of all the frames until the next **I frame**, like so:

The column in question is ['pict_type'], possible values are [I, P, B, i] and I'm only interested in starting a new count on every I value.

[image]

Comment: investigate  `groupby`

Comment: Many thanks @NoobVB, reply as a answer so i can give you the points.
`filtered_frames_video.groupby((filtered_frames_video["pict_type"] == 'I').cumsum()).cumcount().shift(1) + 1`